# What is causing my screen to not be flush with the browser. Looks like there is a padding, but there isnt

Tags: css, frameworks

I have started to use the CSS framework Bluetrip, and I just noticed that for some reason my layout doesnt line up exactly with the browser.

I only have one example to show, http://justcollect.com/ebay_app/index.php/home/index, but if you look closely, my footer doesnt line up with the bottom of the browser. There is some whitespace there.

Any ideas. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think I see what you see in IE8 in compatibility mode.  Below or above the footer?

Comment: Mmh you really want suggestions without showing your code? What should we do? Guess?

Comment: At first sight with Firbug, it seems that the `HTML` element does not fill the the whole browser viewport, but I cannot see anything wrong in the CSS values.

Comment: do you see the effect of the content: "." from your screen.css in your browser(s)?

Comment: Great call Mark... that seemed to be the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put as answer so you can accept :)

do you see the effect of the `content: "."` from your screen.css in your browser(s)?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at in Firefox using Firebug - that is a great tool to look at what styling is being applied to each particular DOM element, and where each CSS attribute is originating from, what is inheriting, what is overridden.  You can quickly solve a bunch of strange things like that.

Answer (score 1):

In screen.css, change `content: "."` to `content: " "` for `.clearfix:after, .container:after`. The period seems to be confusing the browser.

Comment: Solved the problem... but Mark brought it to my attention first. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CSS reset first:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Thats supposed to be taken care of by the Bluetrip framework.

Comment: Looks like they're not cutting the mustard